# Making different parts of a text (of one div) colored using CSS in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am setting a dynamic message through JS like:

```
A.$("#mydiv").html("Some message");
A.$("#mydiv").append(date+", "+start+" - "+end+". ").css('color','#008A00'); -->//Want only this coloured.
```

But it is making the whole message in the div as coloured.
But I want only the second line message coloured.

How can I do that??

Any leads appreciated!!

Comment: You'll want to wrap it with a span or something and apply the inline css / class to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
var span = $('<span>' + date + ", " + start + " - " + end + ". </span>").css('color','#008A00');
A.$("#mydiv").append(span);
```

You cannot set color just to some part of the text - you can apply it to some specific element and append it to your parent `#mydiv`.

Comment: This is not working. When I did this, the content in span didn't show up only. What could be wrong here?